# Why is there no compiler warning for LINQ queries that are not assigned to variables

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a list called `names`:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Mike", "Steve", "Alan", "John" };
```

Now if I use the `List<T>.Sort` method on the list `names` :

```
names.Sort();
```

The list `names` will be sorted :

> "Alan", "John", "Mike", "Steve"

Let's say I use LINQ `OrderBy` instead of `Sort` on the initial list `names`:

```
names.OrderBy(x => x);
```

The initial list `names` will not be sorted :

> "Mike", "Steve", "Alan", "John"

I know if I want to sort the list `names` with LINQ `OrderBy` I have to assign the query to a variable:

```
var orderedNames = names.OrderBy(x => x);
```

The initial list `names` stays unsorted but `orderedNames` will hold the sorted names of the initial list:

> "Alan", "John", "Mike", "Steve"

I am curious why there is no compiler warning for LINQ queries that are not assigned to variables, because calling `names.OrderBy(x => x);`without assign it first to a variable is useless.

Comment: BTW: `var orderedNames = names.OrderBy(x => x);` doesn't sort anything unless you start to enumerate on it

Comment: [Resharper flags this as “Return value of pure method is not used”](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReturnValueOfPureMethodIsNotUsed.html)

Comment: Note that it's not easy to figure out given function has no side effects, and so is "useless" in given context. Resharper devs basically had to evaluate a lot of framework functions by hand to implement feature mentioned in above comment.

Comment: Maybe this seems like a silly question to somebody, but I got the motive today for asking this question because I was answering another question where the OP forgot to assign his query to a variable.

Comment: I don't consider it silly, pretty normal question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is there no compiler warning for LINQ queries that are not assigned to variables

That's a feature. Features do not exist by default and have to be removed. Features need to be thought of, designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped.

All those things need to happen in order for you to have that feature. None of them happened. Hence, no feature.

If you'd like to implement the feature, go for it. The compiler is open sourced.  If you'd like to advocate that someone else implement it, go for it; the design process is also in the open.

If you're going to implement it, while you're at it you can also look for things like calls to `Trim` or `ToLower` and so on, on strings, that are never used.

Now, note that "not assigned to a variable" is insufficient.  For example:

```
names.OrderBy(whatever).ToList().ForEach(whatever);
```

assigns nothing to a variable, but you don't want to warn on that. Similarly

```
Foo(names.OrderBy(whatever))
```

assigns to a variable (a parameter) via a call, not an assignment.

Similarly

```
x = y ? names.OrderBy(whatever) : whatever;
```

does not assign directly, but the value is still used.  **Be very careful**.  The compiler already has a detector that correctly determines if an expression is used for its value, so study that.

Now, maybe your question is "what are difficulties or other 'points against' doing a feature like this?"

The problem is always *false positives*. False positives are scenarios where the code works correctly, it works as it was intended by the developer to work, the code is understandable by the reader, and it still gets a warning. At best false positives annoy the developer, but it gets a lot worse. False positives can undermine trust in the compiler, and they can lead people to change working code into wrong code that doesn't warn.

Let's look at a subtle case. Suppose we have something horrid like this:

```
giraffes.Select(g => { g.Feed(); return 1; }).ToList();
```

This is *terrible* code. But the warning *must not* be something like "Expression statement containing query is useless", because that's a false positive. The user is doing something very, *very* wrong here, but they are *not* making a query that is useless; this query feeds all the giraffes.

The mistake here is *writing a query that is useful only for its side effects*. Queries are not supposed to have side effects, and this is a super crappy way to write `foreach(var g in giraffes) g.Feed();`

Warnings have to not just be *accurate* 99.99% of the time, they have to *identify the real problem* whenever possible.  That's a super hard problem, and the compiler team has enough on their plate already.

There is a lesson here, and that is: think about what bad practices you are trying to prevent when you design a language. C# is really good at preventing lots of the classic bad practices that C and C++ programmers fall into. (And some that Java programmers fall into). But it is bad at making a distinction between "useful for value" and "useful for side effects" because that distinction is not captured in a way that is easy for a compiler to understand or for a developer to represent.  Some languages are really good at making that distinction, like languages in the CAML family.

Comment: I doubt that I can implement this fature in the compiler. I was just curious. Anyway thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @SlavenTojić: You're welcome. If you are interested in the design process that we'd go through to decide what warnings are worth doing, I wrote a bit about that back in 2011: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/03/03/danger-will-robinson/

Answer (score 0):

> calling `names.OrderBy(x => x);` without assign it first to a variable is useless.

Just because something is useless doesn't mean the compiler will (or should) refuse it.

You can demonstrate your point not just with LINQ queries but with any method.

Like if you had some list, and you do a `list.IndexOf(-1);`. You aren't storing that value in anything, so for all intents and purposes it's useless, but it's a valid statement nonetheless.

Comment: The question doesn't ask why the compiler doesn't refuse it, the question asks why the compiler doesn't warn about it. The compiler will by design warn about a lot of valid code that it will also compile. The `.IndexOf` example doesn't invalidate the question, it *supports* the question: it shows that this has potentially been a problem for longer than the OP thought.